# Deploying Backbone App to Node JS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

Trying to build an app with nodejs and backbone. 
 Till now I am running node js server with express routes. These simple nodejs routes just sending the data back to Backbone models.
I am running backbone app by opening html file directly to the browser and defining node js urls in the model.
Now the problem comes when I try to implement `Backbone Router` in the application. If I directly open the html file it won't work.
Question is how would I deploy backbone app to the node server?
**Directory Structure:**

```
app
--index.html
--view
----appView.js
--model
----appModel.js
--server
----server.js
--controller
----router.js
```

**appView.js**

```
var LoginForm = Backbone.View.extend({
    template:_.template('<input type="text" id="email" name="email" />'+
                        '<input type="password" id="password" name="password" />'+
                         '<input type="button" id="login" value="Login"/>'),
    events: {
        'click #login':'goIn'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },
    goIn: function() {
        console.log(this.$('#password').val());
        this.model.set({"email":this.$('#email').val(), "password":this.$('#password').val()});
        this.model.goIn();
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
        this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));
    }
});
```

**Model**

```
var LoginFormModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults: {
        email:"",
        password:""
      },
      goIn: function(req, resp) {
        console.log('hey whats up?'+JSON.stringify(this));
        //this.save();
      }
  });

  var loginModel = new LoginFormModel();
```

**Node server**

```
var http = require('http'),
    express = require('express');
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello App');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the [navigate](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate) function :

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : {
        "": "home", // will be 
        "login" : "login"
    },

    home: function() {
        // your home page
    }

    login: function() {
        var loginModel = new LoginModel();
        var loginView = new LoginView({model: loginModel});
        loginModel.fetch();
    }
})

new Router();
Backbone.history.start();
```

and when you want to go to the login page wherever you are :

```
Backbone.history.navigate('login', { trigger: true });
```

Comment: In this case would it go into View's `goIn()`?